# How can a noSql database be ACID compliant when they don't have referential constraints?

Tags: nosql

From Wikipedia:

Consistency (ACID)

"In database systems, a consistent transaction is one that does not violate any integrity constraints during its execution. If a transaction leaves the database in an illegal state, it is aborted and an error is reported."

If a noSql database doesn't have a concept of integrity constraints, then how are they claiming to be ACID compliant? It strikes me that they think of consistency as something else (perhaps sameness across a cluster), or that without constraints it can't violate any and so they pass by default.

Comment: Many NoSQL databases are not claiming to be fully acid-compliant.

Comment: They replace the "C" (Consistency) with another definition of consistency like Eventual Consistency (sometimes in the future will the modification be visible in all parts of the cluster and conflicts needs to be resolved along the way) or Local Consistency (the consistency is assured only within one single node and not throughout the cluster). If you need to have true ACID you should look into NewSQL databases!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute an statement (insert for example) several tasks need to be done, create an index, persist the new record, arrange cache elements etc, consistency means that if one of those steps fails then the other should be, somehow, reversed, the index could not point to elements that does not exist, the id could not be repeated, etc. that is consistency too. Acid is a property that is not exclusive to the RDBMS systems but any system that support states.